# inheriting Windows Forms Controls in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I have a custom control for a LayoutPanel that holds child controls. I want the ensure that all child controls contain a certain property from the Parent container of the layout panel.   I attempted to use the following code to create various child controls which will ensure storage of the property *ChartPropertyOwner*, relying on inheritance to assume the type (Labels, Buttons, standard forms controls)

```
public partial class ManipControl : System.Windows.Forms.Control {

        public ChartPropertySet ChartPropertyOwner { get; set; }

        public ManipControl(ChartPropertySet _cps) {
            ChartPropertyOwner = _cps;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
}
```

I initialize with the following statement:

```
Button btnManipDel= new ManipControl(_cps);
```

I receive the error:

*Cannot implicitly convert type 'ManipControl' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'*

Why does implicit conversion fail and how do I resolve this?

Comment: A Button is a Button and has no relationship to a ManipControl. If you want to have a Button control expose your properties impliment an Interface IMyInterface and inherit from Button. public class MyButton: Button, IMyInterface { // Do the business }

Comment: I don't think it is good idea to create a control without a public parameterless constructor.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that @ja72?

Comment: Creating controls that _don't_ have a parameterless constructor will cause problems when using them in the Windows Forms designer.   The designer will have no idea how to satisfy the parameters to the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ManipControl->System.Windows.Forms.Control

Button->System.Windows.Forms.Control

Button is not guaranteed to be a ManipControl

To resolve this, you can just explicitly cast to a Button.

```
Button btnManipDel= (Button)new ManipControl(_cps);
```

I don't know that this is the best thing to do as a Button != ManipControl. The only guaranteed functions will come from their base class of System.Windows.Forms.Control. That is the better class to cast to, and I believe will implicitly cast (but am not positive):

```
System.Windows.Forms.Control btnManipDel= new ManipControl(_cps);
```

You might want to read up on [Liskov's Substition Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and contravariance and covariance.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion fails because whilst ManipControl is a Control, and Button is a control, the ManipControl is not a Button.

You could change your class to an interface and create a new ManipButton:

```
public interface IManipControl
{
    int ChartPropertyOwner { get; set; }
}

public class ManipButton : Button, IManipControl
{
    public int ChartPropertyOwner{get;set;}
}
```